# Document version changes when copied to another library

Tags: sharepoint-online, word

We are trying to use SharePoint as a document management system aligned with CMMC compliance.  We have a controlled document library which maintains all the documents, versions, etc. as well as specific metadata which determines the documents availability.  For example, Current Release vs. draft.  Each of the documents has a header/footer with version, doc ID and some other information as part of the document control mechanism.

The issue is that Current Release documents need to be copied to various projects for consumption...meaning the docs are filled out once they are copied to a project site collection.

The issue is this...if I copy a current release document to my PC the versioning and other metadata is maintained.  But, as soon as I copy it to some test library emulating a project the version information and other metadata changes.  For example, a doc with revision 19 shows up as revision 15 when copied to a project document library.

I tried document copying using Power Automate and PowerShell and the built in copy feature in Sharepoint but the information changes.  Per CMMS we need to account for which documents people are using so versions are important to be in compliance with CMMC.

Is there a workaround to remedy this or is it some setting I'm not aware of in SharePoint?

Thanks in advance